# Android - Realm Exception: Could Not Find RealmJsonImpl, Class Not Found Exception

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception, realm

**Here is my Realm Object:**

```
public class StringThisClassRealm extends RealmObject {
    String string = "";

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

**I call this onCreate of my Activity for testing purpsoe:**

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
realm.beginTransaction();
StringThisClassRealm cr = realm.createObject(StringThisClassRealm.class);
cr.setString("String");
realm.commitTransaction();
```

When I debugged, it never went through the first line `Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);`

**App Crashes, and this is my logTrace:**

```
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300): Process: uk.org.humanfocus.hfi, PID: 12300 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.org.humanfocus.hfi/uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.sclr.CompetencyAssessment}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.RealmJsonImpl 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300): Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.RealmJsonImpl 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at io.realm.Realm.getRealmJson(Realm.java:268) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at io.realm.Realm.<init>(Realm.java:165) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:513) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:486) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:404) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:366) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:347) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.sclr.CompetencyAssessment.onCreate(CompetencyAssessment.java:125) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   ... 11 more 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.realm.RealmJsonImpl 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at io.realm.Realm.getRealmJson(Realm.java:263) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   ... 21 more 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/realm/RealmJsonImpl 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   ... 25 more 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.realm.RealmJsonImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/uk.org.humanfocus.hfi-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/uk.org.humanfocus.hfi-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497) 
05-19 13:15:44.440: E/AndroidRuntime(12300):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
```

**Here you can see the factory path:**

[image]

Comment: Please tell @oMiKeY about your jdk

Comment: what version of Realm are you using? Can you show your dependencies?

Comment: It sounds like the annotation processor isn't running for some reason. Try to check the Gradle log from Android studio or run ./gradlew clean assemble from the command line to see if it reports any errors or warnings.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior i am using eclipse

Comment: Please try to add the `@RealmClass` annotation to your model class. Eclipse often needs the annotation to trigger the annotation processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add annotation of `@RealmClass` to trigger the annotation pre-processor which initates/triggers the `annotation process`. It will also itself include the reference. Rest is Fine